# Paste Filtered Sheet

Tags: excel

I have a sheet of rates. Column A is the rate. Column B is the effective date. Supposed I wanted to escalate the rates for 2020 by 5%. My first approach would be to filter the date column for 2020 and then enter a formula in column C like, =A2*1.05. Then I would copy column C and paste values in Column A. However, when I attempt this exact approach, the paste doesn't work. The paste seems to ignore the filter and affect rows that are outside the filter condition.
Is there a way to get paste to work in a filtered sheet?

Comment: You could also incorporate `IF` and `YEAR` into your function in column C, without filtering at all.

Comment: Ben, beat me to it! To avoid this issue altogether, you can also just calculate the whole column with a formula like `=IF(B2=2020, A2*1.05, A2)` which says if the year is 2020, scale up by 5%, otherwise keep the current value.

Comment: it seems like copy selects visible cell but paste doesn't work on visible only. Shouldn't they work the same?